# Java HashMap behavior is not up to O(1) mark

Tags: java, hashmap

When I run this program

```
public class MyHashMapOperationsDebug {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyHashMap hashMap = new MyHashMap();//MyHashMap is replica of HashMap
        for (int i=1;i<=11;i++)
        hashMap.put(i, i+100);
        }
}
```

and `MyHashMap.java` has

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {  //replica of HashMap's addEntry method  

Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
**System.out.println("bucketIndex : " + bucketIndex);**
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
bucketIndex : 7  
bucketIndex : 14  
bucketIndex : 4  
bucketIndex : 13  
bucketIndex : 1  
bucketIndex : 8  
bucketIndex : 2  
bucketIndex : 11  
bucketIndex : 11  
bucketIndex : 2  
bucketIndex : 8
```

Why some keys go to same bucket, even when only 11 keys are stored in map of size 16? E.g. bucket at index 2, and 11 has two keys each

**EDIT:**
After Reading inputs below One question : What will be the complexity in above case where HashMap & Integer of Java is used. Is it O(1) ?

Comment: A hash table is only asymptotically O(1), it can be O(n) in the worst case. The pathological worst case would be the one where each item was hashed to the same index in the map.

Comment: It's called statistics.

Comment: Side note: It highly depends on the quality of your has function as well. If it really counts, you may need to override the `hashCode()` method.

Comment: Asymptotically speaking, "yes O(1)". Unless you've screwed up your hash function.

Answer (score 13):

Because it's impossible, without knowing all the keys in advance, to design an algorithm that will guarantee that they will be evenly distributed. And even when knowing all the keys in advance, if two of them have the same hashCode, they will always be in the same bucket.

That doesn't mean the HashMap isn't O(1). Even assuming that every bucket has 2 entries, regardless of the number of entries in the map, that still makes every get operation execute in time that doesn't depend on the number of entries in the map, which is the definition of O(1).

Comment: regardless of the number of entries in the map: so for example, if you have 100 entries in the map and say 90 of them are collisions. So i will have chain of 90 elements. Will the get operation still be O(1). because i think we need to traverse this list at the most to 90 elements.

Comment: That would be an example of a map with a bad distribution algorithm (which is not the case of HashMap), or of a Key class with a bad hashCode() implementation. For example, if the implementation of hashCode() is `return 1;`, storing such keys in a HashMap will make it O(n). But that's a problem with the Key class, not with HashMap. Assuming a good distribution of hashCodes, HashMap will be O(1).

Comment: Thank you for the reply as always. I have few doubts: 1) if two Keys has same hashcode they will go to same bucket. but here I am using int(autoboxed to Integer in Java 5) and as per hashcode() method in Integerclass - it returns the value.So in that case all keys should go to different hash buckets. 2) I got confused on O(1), will review it

Comment: O(1) is best case. The worst case is O(n). It may be possible to choose keys such that the performance is the worst case.

Comment: @Naroji: the HashMap doesn't have 2^32 buckets. It only has a few. So each integer returned by hashCode is reduced to another integer between 0 and the number of buckets by an algorithm that does its best to have an even distribution. In that case, you got two collisions. Adding more values in the map will eventually increase the number of buckets, and keys will be redistributed among these new buckets to ensure the distributionis as even as possible.

Comment: @zerocool - That reasoning is faulty.  Big Oh is about the behaviour of the upper bound limit of the cost function as N tends to infinity.  If you get 90% of the entries in the same bucket as N tends to infinity, then the performance will actually be `O(N)`.

Comment: @StephenC : thats the point that i was trying to make. Lookup operation should not be generalized to O(1) always.

Comment: @zerocool - What your comment *actually* says (to me) is that `get` will be `O(1)` ... which is a strange way of saying it is `O(N)` :-)

Comment: @zerocool - But what I just said is ignoring the practical limits of Java `HashMap`: 1) `hashcode()` delivers a 32 bit hashcode, and 2) there are at most 2^31 buckets / chains in a `HashMap`. These mean that `HashMap` is only `O(1)` (best case) up to `2^31` elements, and then it switches to `O(N)` ... with a very small constant of proportionality. We don't normally mention this, because `HashMaps` that large are going to bring all sorts of other problems with them ... and *because* the `C` is very small beyond the transition point.

Comment: @StephenC hehe :). one question: say my hashCode implementation is such that, for 99/100 objects i get the same hashCode but equals says that they are different.In this case we will have chaining for 99 elements,right? what will be the look up time? (Please correct me if i am wrong, also i know this kind of scenario is rare or may not even be right to implement hashCode and equals this way).

Comment: @zerocool: that's the example I gave above (except my example was 100% and not 99%, by always returning 1 as the hashCode). In this case, the lookup is O(n). This implementation of hashCode respects the contract of hashCode(), but is obviously a very bad implementation of this contract, since it drastically reduces the performance of hash-based data structures containing instances of this class.

Comment: @zerocool is correct.  I just want to add that *anything* that results in an uneven distribution hash values results in *worst case* behaviour that is `O(N)`.  However if the unevenness is minor and `N` doesn't get too large, the worst case behaviour is unlikely to be problematic.  Yes ... hash table behaviour is **really difficult** to analyse / characterize.

Answer (score 1):

> What will be the complexity in above case where HashMap & Integer of Java is used. Is it O(1) ?

Yes.  The `Integer.hashcode()` method returns the value of the `Integer` itself, and that will be uniformly distributed across the space of possible hash values.

So the performance of the hash table will be optimal; i.e. `O(1)` for `get` operations and `O(1)` (amortized) for `put` operations.  And since there are only 2^32 unique keys possible, we don't need to consider the issue of how `HashMap` scales beyond that point.

Comment: As you said> 2^32 unique keys possible. SO does that mean the max number of buckets in a hashmap can be 2^32, even it has 10 of million of entries

Answer (score 0):

E.g. bucket at index 2, and 11 has two keys each: thats because of the hashCollision. HashMap can give a performance of O(n) in look up provided that you have Hash Collision for all n elements. Thats the bad design of hashing algorithm.

And infact in a way you can say that to avoid these collisions, you have some extra space being allocated. Because your hashing technique makes sure that you dont have many collisions and to do that you obviously need extra backets.

But at the same time, you cant avoid collision completely, because if your hashing technique is such that each bucket will be having only one entry, you will need a lot of space. So, actually hashCollisions, in a limit are good to have.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to know the key distribution beforehand to design an o(1) hash function. Even though you know the key distribution also your key may map to same slot. So you need to do rehashing once your load factor moves to a certain fraction. If suppose your map size is 16 and you have 17 keys then it will have collision. so in this situation you need to have some mechanism to rehash the map to remove potential collisions.

The find operation in hashmap is asymptotically O(1) but it can GO TO o(n) as well.